# Authomatic Flask Oauth2 how to hide provider code from url?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0

I am developing an app the uses Flask and [Authomatic](http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/#) for Oauth2 authentication both with Google and Facebook. It is working just fine, but once in a log in the url on the browser show some state/code hash used on the Oauth2 process. How do I get rid of it? The showcase app from Authomatic does the same thing but quickly somehow hide it from the user.

if I do, the url is clean but I cannot pass any arguments to my endpoint fuction.

```
full_url = url_for('flaskio.index')
return redirect(full_url)
```

With this, the url keeps the state argument from Authomatic, but I can pass the arguments I want.

```
from app.flaskio.routes import index
return index(currentt_user, socialuser)
```

Endpoint

```
@socketio.route('/')
@login_required
def index(current_userr=None, socialuser=None):

    global thread
    if thread is None:
        thread = Thread(target=background_thread)
        thread.start()
        # import pdb
        # pdb.set_trace()

    return render_template('socket.html', cescouser=socialuser, current_user=current_userr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply save whatever information you need in the flask session and redirect to an URL not containing any tokens.

Comment: I have tried 

messages = json.dumps(result.user.email)
session['messages'] = messages
return redirect(url_for('.do_foo', messages=messages))

but then i still get something like /?messages=email@gmail

Comment: tried also request.args['state'] = '', but just realized the request is an immutable dict.